# Websphere - Hosted Application Not Running

Tags: websphere

I am new to the application server environment. I have installed Websphere Application Server v8.5 and DB2 v10.1 as the database server. I need to host an application on websphere, which uses a JDBC data-source connection for connecting a DB2 database.

Now, the app has been successfully deployed and has been started on websphere admin console. When I am trying to run the application using //hostname:portname/application, I am getting the following error:

```
An unexpected error has occured.
Please consult your system logs for more detailed information.
```

After getting into the system.out log in "C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1", I have found the following error:

```
[8/19/13 5:23:55:298 UTC] 0000019d LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[8/19/13 5:23:55:298 UTC] 0000019d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletNameNotFound]: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy348.getCallerIps(Unknown Source)
    at com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.CallerIpFilter.doFilter(CallerIpFilter.java:40)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: com.rsa.csd.config.IGenConfigService$GenConfigException: runtime.ex
    at com.rsa.csd.config.AAOPGenConfigProxyImpl.invoke(AAOPGenConfigProxyImpl.java:126)
    at com.rsa.csd.config.GenConfigServiceDynamicProxy.invoke(GenConfigServiceDynamicProxy.java:68)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The CacheManager has been shut down. It can no longer be used.
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.checkStatus(CacheManager.java:1158)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getEhcache(CacheManager.java:807)
    at com.rsa.csd.cache.EhcacheWrapper.getCache(EhcacheWrapper.java:30)
    at com.rsa.csd.cache.EhcacheWrapper.get(EhcacheWrapper.java:23)
    at com.rsa.csd.config.GenConfigCommandBase.getRegionContextHeirarchies(GenConfigCommandBase.java:95)
    at com.rsa.csd.config.GenConfigGetCommand.handleGet(GenConfigGetCommand.java:241)
    at com.rsa.csd.config.GenConfigGetCommand.execute(GenConfigGetCommand.java:55)
    at com.rsa.csd.config.AAOPGenConfigProxyImpl.invoke(AAOPGenConfigProxyImpl.java:119)
    ... 26 more
```

Web.xml file for this application is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
    <web-app id="WebApp_1376545306753">

<icon/>

<display-name>My App</display-name>

<distributable/>

<context-param>
    <param-name>bootstrapConfigFile</param-name>
    <param-value>pmBootstrapConfigs.xml</param-value>
    <description>
        Bootstraps db connection and configloading, used by
        PassMarkContextLoaderServlet
    </description>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>loadLocalConfigsOnly</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    <description>
        If true, reloading will be done from file only; if false,
        local configs will be loaded if the localFileBasePaths is
        specified.
    </description>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>localFilesBasePath</param-name>
    <param-value>configs</param-value>
    <description>
        Directory/Path where the local files required for the
        configuration framework reside. This path can be relative to
        classpath (classes directory) or an absolute path
    </description>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>secondaryBasePathList</param-name>
    <param-value>C:\RAA-Main\configs</param-value>
    <description>
        Directory/Path where the external files required for the
        configuration framework reside. This path can be relative to
        classpath (classes directory) or an absolute path
    </description>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>configTreeName</param-name>
    <param-value>PMRoot</param-value>
    <description>
        Name of the configTree in Db to be used for this application
    </description>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CallerIpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.CallerIpFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>WebServiceLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.passmarksecurity.filter.WebServiceLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.SessionCredentialsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>XSSDetectionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.XSSDetectionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!--
<filter>
    <filter-name>WSDLAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.WSDLAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
-->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CallerIpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XSSDetectionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/contextManager</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XSSDetectionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/logManager</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebServiceLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/AuthService</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/healthCheck</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/healthCheck/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/contextManager</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/contextManager/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/logManager</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/logManager/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>credentialsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RsaContextLoader</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Rsa Context LoaderListener Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.passmarksecurity.servlet.RsaContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PMContextManager</servlet-name>
    <display-name>PM Context Manager</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.passmarksecurity.servlet.PassMarkContextManagerServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogManager</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Log Manager</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.passmarksecurity.servlet.LogManagerServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HealthCheck</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Health Check</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.passmarksecurity.servlet.HealthCheckServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ContextServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>save the root context full path to be used for axis client configuration creation</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rsa.csd.acsp.servlet.ContextServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>6</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PMContextManager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/contextManager</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogManager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logManager</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HealthCheck</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/healthCheck</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xsd</extension>
    <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- error pages -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsps/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsps/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsps/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1376545306753">
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/PassMarkDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1376545306754">
    <description>Work Manager</description>
    <res-ref-name>wm/default</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<env-entry>
    <description>Required when accessing PM core database under DB2 using DAOFactory</description>
    <env-entry-name>db2SchemaName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>RSA_CORE_SCHEMA</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

One of the application logs state the following errors :

```
    2013-08-19 01:14:34,525 +0000 ERROR - [] | [] | [] | [SYSTEM_ERROR | Failed to initialize the context: null]
    2013-08-19 04:54:03,157 +0000 WARN - [] | [] | [] | [Alert type=device-type-detector-load-failed, application=UNKNOWN, site=site, host=localhost, time=Mon Aug 19 04:54:03 UTC 2013, message values="", Failed to load device type detector data file, Failed to load device type detector data file from ]
    2013-08-19 04:54:03,173 +0000 ERROR - [] | [] | [] | [CONFIG_ERROR | Initializing PassMark config context failed: exception loading the ApplicationContext for this configSpace PMRoot because: Error creating bean with name 'deviceTypeDetector' defined in ConfigResource: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: \
    CAUSE: Error creating bean with name 'deviceTypeDetector' defined in ConfigResource: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: \]
    2013-08-19 04:54:03,219 +0000 ERROR - [] | [] | [] | [SYSTEM_ERROR | Failed to initialize the context: null]
```

Also need to add that other applications are running fine on this environment. I am facing this issue only with one of the applications. I am working on Amazon AWS EC2 M1 medium-size instance...with 3.75 GB memory and 64-bit windows server 2012 platform...with JDK 6 update 45.

I know this may be naive but I have no idea about the Java environment as I have been from the database/data-warehousing domain. Please guide me how to find the actual cause and resolve this problem. I would also appreciate if the experts suggest me some good online blogs to learn more about java applications and websphere basics.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Experts, Please Help** I have gone through a lot of blogs online...not able to understand the problem with this application...Please let me know if you need any other info...I am willing try anything to make it work ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your filter `com.rsa.csd.servlet.filters.CallerIpFilter` throws `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` at line 40. Down to stacktrace there is a problem with your Ehcache initialization.

So, first of all I'd like to try upgrade to [BigMemory](http://docs.terracotta.org/confluence/display/release/BigMemory+4.0,+Ehcache+2.7+Platform+Support) - [Download](http://terracotta.org/downloads). Actually, it is upgraded Ehcache and there is free prod package up to 4 cores and 32 gig of mem i think.

Otherwise you should provide info about your JDK, os architecture and source codes of classes from stacktraces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I am working on Amazon AWS EC2 M1 medium system...with 3.75 Gig Memory, 64-bit windows server 2012 platform...Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 45

I am sorry...but I have no idea how to check the classes from stack traces...where should I check those ?

Please pardon my ignorance, I am a beginner altogether :(